# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

i m going to build a bicubic image in a function and then i want to use it in one of my layers in API model,i see this error,how can i solve it ? thank u !!

```
def model_bicubic(image):
    image = Image.open(image, mode = 'r')
    width, height = image.size
    image_bicubic = image.resize((width*2, height*2), Image.BICUBIC)

    return image_bicubic
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the following way:

```
def load_image(img_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels = 3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, size = (width, height), method = 'bicubic')
    img = img / 255.0
    return img
```

Worked for me.